# What's the story with ExpressionType.Assign?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I was under the impression that assignment was not possible inside a lambda expression.  E.g., the following (admittedly not very useful) code

```
Expression<Action<int, int>> expr = (x, y) => y = x;
```

Produces the compiler error

```
An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator
```

And yet, according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361179.aspx), one can programmatically create an assignment expression using `Expression.Assign`.  Unless I am mistaken, the following code produces an equivalent `Expression`:

```
ParameterExpression xparam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
ParameterExpression yparam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
BinaryExpression body = Expression.Assign(yparam, xparam);
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Action<int, int>>(body, xparam, yparam);
var cexpr = expr.Compile();
```

In this case, the compiler does not complain.  I feel like I am missing some important distinction here.

Comment: The compiler error is misleading. It means that the compiler cannot generate the code for you to create an assignment (so that LINQ providers are not all required to support it). You are free to create whatever you want.

Comment: @Gabe you should answerify that comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

usr's answer is correct; to expand on it somewhat:

You are not missing an important *distinction*, you are missing an important *dimension*: time.

If you look at the documentation carefully you'll note that the `Assign` node was added in .NET 4.0.

Expression trees were added to C# 3.0, which shipped with .NET 3.5.

The team that owns the expression tree library has added many features to it since .NET 3.5 shipped. Using those features to allow more expressions to be in an expression tree in the C# language did not make the cut for C# 4.0 or C# 5.0.  There's no reason to *not* do the feature; it's a perfectly sensible feature. But the language designers do not require a reason to *not* do a feature; they require a reason *to* spend the budget on a feature.

In this case, richer expression trees in C# simply did not make it high enough on the priority list. If you'd like that feature to be higher priority then you can open an issue on connect.microsoft.com and request it. Your request is more likely to be implemented if you include a compelling scenario for the feature.

Comment: OK, this clarifies things.  The reason I asked is that it appeared to be the case that only side-effect-free lambdas were possible.  But as I look through Expression types, I see many operations which change state.  I don't have a compelling use-case yet for the un-lambda-able Expression types, but it would be nice to be able to enforce purity for user-defined lambdas in general.

Comment: @DanBarowy: Expression trees *in the initial release* were designed for side effects free operations because that is what LINQ needed, though they were not 100% strict; for example, a method that has a ref parameter can be expressed in an expression tree.

Answer (score 10):

You are not misunderstanding anything. C# is intentionally restrictive in the kinds of expression trees it can generate for you. There's no principled reason why it couldn't have that feature. It just wasn't invested in. (Creating features takes away resources. Would you rather have `async/await` or expression tree statements? Clearly the first option is more useful.).

You also cannot generate other statements like `if` or `while` although they *are* in the expression tree API starting with .NET 4. (You can construct and compile complex control flows with expression trees now).